# Refreshing every minutes

Tags: vb.net, web-services, visual-studio-2005

In a form, there is a label. It shows whether web service is connected or not at every minutes. How to code to repeat this process? Will I use the thread or timer? Please share me.

Comment: Firstly - Why are you keeping the web service open if your not actually using it?

Comment: There is no .SynchronizingObject method under class timer

Answer (score 1):

You will need a timer object in order to run the code every X minutes.  Using a separate thread to check the web service only needs to be done if it will take a while to check and you want your form to remain responsive during this time.

Using a timer is very easy:

```
Private WithEvents timer As New System.Timers.Timer

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'Set interval to 1 minute
    timer.Interval = 60000 

    'Synchronize with current form, or else an error will occur when trying to
    'update the UI from within the elapsed event
    timer.SynchronizingObject = Me
End Sub


Private Sub timer_Elapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles timer.Elapsed
    'Add code here to check if the web service is updated and update label
End Sub
```